# Failing to append to dictionary. Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am experiencing a strange faulty behaviour, where a dictionary is only appended once and I can not add more key value pairs to it.

My code reads in a multi-line string and extracts substrings via split(), to be added to a dictionary. I make use of conditional statements. **Strangely only the key:value pairs under the first conditional statement are added.**

Therefore I can not complete the dictionary.

**How can I solve this issue?**

Minimal code:

```
#I hope the '\n' is sufficient or use '\r\n'
example = "Name: Bugs Bunny\nDOB: 01/04/1900\nAddress: 111 Jokes Drive, Hollywood Hills, CA 11111, United States"

def format(data):
    dic = {}
    for line in data.splitlines():
        #print('Line:', line)
        if ':' in line:
            info = line.split(': ', 1)[1].rstrip() #does not work with files
            #print('Info: ', info)
            if ' Name:' in info: #middle name problems! /maiden name
                dic['F_NAME'] = info.split(' ', 1)[0].rstrip()
                dic['L_NAME'] = info.split(' ', 1)[1].rstrip()
            elif 'DOB' in info: #overhang              
                dic['DD'] = info.split('/', 2)[0].rstrip()
                dic['MM'] = info.split('/', 2)[1].rstrip()
                dic['YY'] = info.split('/', 2)[2].rstrip()
            elif 'Address' in info:
                dic['STREET'] = info.split(', ', 2)[0].rstrip()
                dic['CITY'] = info.split(', ', 2)[1].rstrip()
                dic['ZIP'] = info.split(', ', 2)[2].rstrip() 
    return dic





if __name__ == '__main__':
   x = format(example)
   for v, k in x.iteritems():
       print v, k
```

Comment: Why are you testing for `' Name:'` when you have been splitting on `:` and when your sample data contains no space before `Name`?

Comment: Also, `info` contains everything **after** the `:`, so none of your tests will work.

Comment: As expected, I get an empty dictionary from your function.

Comment: a way to solve is to just step through the code and look at the data as you're processing it, one step at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work, at all. You split off the name before the colon and discard it, looking only at the value after the colon, stored in `info`. That value never contains the names you are looking for; `Name`, `DOB` and `Address` all are part of the line *before* the `:`.

Python lets you assign to multiple names at once; make use of this when splitting:

```
def format(data):
    dic = {}
    for line in data.splitlines():
        if ':' not in line:
            continue
        name, _, value = line.partition(':')
        name = name.strip()
        if name == 'Name':
            dic['F_NAME'], dic['L_NAME'] = value.split(None, 1)  # strips whitespace for us
        elif name == 'DOB':
            dic['DD'], dic['MM'], dic['YY'] = (v.strip() for v in value.split('/', 2))
        elif name == 'Address':
            dic['STREET'], dic['CITY'], dic['ZIP'] = (v.strip() for v in value.split(', ', 2))
    return dic
```

I used `str.partition()` here rather than limit `str.split()` to just one split; it is slightly faster that way.

For your sample input this produces:

```
>>> format(example)
{'CITY': 'Hollywood Hills', 'ZIP': 'CA 11111, United States', 'L_NAME': 'Bunny', 'F_NAME': 'Bugs', 'YY': '1900', 'MM': '04', 'STREET': '111 Jokes Drive', 'DD': '01'}
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(format(example))
{'CITY': 'Hollywood Hills',
 'DD': '01',
 'F_NAME': 'Bugs',
 'L_NAME': 'Bunny',
 'MM': '04',
 'STREET': '111 Jokes Drive',
 'YY': '1900',
 'ZIP': 'CA 11111, United States'}
```

Comment: Thanks, Martijn Pieters. Alright I see my down vote as justified. Had fried my brain with too much coding the last three days. And now where seeing bugs where none are. I think we all have been there.

Comment: Of, course I know to retrieve tuples, yet some of the strings are more intricate to process as shown in this minimal example, that why I were taking them one by one.